# How to detect whether audio is playing or not in a web application in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

I am working on a web application which left many audios in a page. Basically I am developing conversation part in application where audio messages are also sent and received. I want to detect that either audio is playing or not to prevent refreshing of messaging block, while audio is playing.

Comment: [HTMLMediaElement.pause()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause)

Comment: You need to provide some more information

Comment: Actually i am working on a web project. In this project i made feature of conversation. Messages in conversation can be text or audio like what's app. Now i am refreshing automatically specific portion of page in which sent or received messages are displayed after 10 second. Now there is a problem that when length of audio message is more than 10 second, message portion refreshed after 10 second and audio message restarted and could not be played more after 10 second. I want to detect that when audio is playing, than message portion should not refresh until audio end..
could any help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to detect if your audio is playing currently or not with the help of java script.

For example :

I am assuming id of your element is "audio"

A)   Via paused/play attribute

```
 var audio = $('#audio');
 audioElement = audio.get(0);

 if (!audioElement.paused) {
    // here do your stuff
 }
```

B) Via duration

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('audio');

if (myAudio.duration > 0 && !myAudio.paused) {

    //Its playing...do your job

 } else {

    //Not playing...maybe paused, stopped or never played.

 }
```